# Using While Loop after button press to search a multidimensional array for a value

Tags: java, android, button, while-loop

I am relatively new to making applications for an Android phone and there is a problem that I have been trying to solve for the past week.  What I am trying to do is take in 4 variables, 3 of which is from spinners and using while loops and case statements to search through the database to send a string into a TextView box.  The main problem I have is the while loops after the button press errors out the program.  I have tried implementing different ways like using a runnable and thread to work through it but have not had any success.  I would greatly appreciate any help.  The way the array is built is a 54x7.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    while(AutoDatabase[i][0] != YearSelect){
        i++;
    }

    while(AutoDatabase[i][1] != MakeSelect){
        i++;
    }

    while(AutoDatabase[i][2] != ModelSelect){
        i++;

    if (LightsOut == "FDTS"){
        Part = AutoDatabase[i][3];
    } else if (LightsOut == "FPTS"){
        Part = AutoDatabase[i][4];
    } else if (LightsOut == "RDTS"){
        Part = AutoDatabase[i][5];
    } else if (LightsOut == "RPTS"){
        Part = AutoDatabase[i][6];
    }

    PartDisplay.setText(Part);
}
```

Comment: == and != do not compare strings by value

Comment: http://www.zparacha.com/java-string-comparison/#.UK1tRhpunYw

Comment: What's `i`? You haven't declared or initialized it here. I'd expect it to be being declared and initialised to 0 at the start of a function like this. Have you changed your code before posting, or is it a class variable?

What error are you getting? I'm guessing an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException once `i` grows beyond the size of your array, but you haven't specified.

What are you actually trying to *do*? It's hard to say what's wrong with your code when its unclear what the intended result is.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  The whole issue was the string comparison.  It works great now.  I had declared i as a global variable that was initialized to 0.